# existe algun algoritmo para saber los cambios que sufrio una variable?

Tags: javascript, html5

bien e intentado hacer que el personaje de mi proyecto se mueva de manera diagonal utilizando el objecto "Evento" con E.KEY y setTimeout para saber en un pequeño lapso de tiempo que teclas se presionaron y asi darle los parametros para seguir.

En fin como puedo saber cuales fueron las ultimas informaciones de la variable E.KEY

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>  
        </head>
        <body>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <input id="text" type="text" value="anonymous"><br>
            <canvas id="camara" width="500" height="500" style="border:5px solid #000000">
            
            <script>
                //creando el objecto "Objecto":
                var Objecto = {
                    //clases de objectos
                    clases: ["madera", "chatarra"],
                    //funcion de crear objecto
                    crear_objecto: function(objecto_id , objecto_nombre){
                        var objecto_id = 0;
                        objecto_nombre = Objecto.clases[0];
                    },
                    dibujar_objectos: function(imagen){
                        var objecto_x = 50;
                        var objecto_y = 50;
                        var imagen = ctx.fillRect(objecto_x , objecto_y , 10 , 10);
                    },
                };
                //creando el objecto "Personaje":
                var Personaje = {
                    cx: 250,
                    cy: 250,
                    //funcion de crear y dibujar el personaje
                    crear: function(){
                        ctx.fillRect(Personaje.cx,Personaje.cy,10,10);
                        //ctx.drawImage(img,Personaje.cx , Personaje.cy);
                        var info = document.getElementById("text").value;
                        ctx.fillText(info,Personaje.cx , Personaje.cy);
                    },
                    //funcion de movimiento del personaje
                    control: function(){
                        document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
                            if(e.key=="w"){
                                if(Personaje.cy == 0){
                                    Personaje.cy = Personaje.cy + 2
                                }else{
                                    Personaje.cy = Personaje.cy - 1
                                }
                            }else if(e.key=="a"){
                                if(Personaje.cx == 0){
                                    Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx + 2
                                }else{
                                    Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx - 1
                                }
                            }else if(e.key=="s"){
                                if(Personaje.cy == 500){
                                    Personaje.cy = Personaje.cy - 2
                                }else{
                                    Personaje.cy = Personaje.cy + 1
                                }
                            }else if(e.key=="d"){
                                if(Personaje.cx == 500){
                                    Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx - 2
                                }else{
                                    Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx + 1
                                }
                            }else{
                                console.log("otra accion");
                            }
                        })
                    },
                };
                //variables globales:
                var canvas;
                var ctx;
                var velocidad = 7;
                
                //creando bucles:
                //bucle de tiempo
                for(velocidad;velocidad<10;velocidad++){
                    Personaje.control();
                };
                //bucle general
                setInterval(function(){
                    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
                    Objecto.dibujar_objectos();
                    Personaje.crear();
                },10);
                //iniciando canvas
                canvas = document.getElementById("camara");
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                //cargando imagen   
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = "pixie.png";
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Cada evento es separado, así que deberías es escuchar cada uno e inferir a partir de alguna lógica, qué está haciendo el usuario. Podrías explicar qué has hecho para lograrlo en vez de poner spam.

Comment: Puedes usar un console.log para saber el valor de la variable en cada movimiento o usar la palabra debugger para debuggear tu script